# How to push unsynced commits to GitHub?

Tags: github

I have a GitHub source control tool added to my copy of Visual Studio 2013 and when I right click on  the solution and make a commit it says created the commit locally. When I try to sync the commit with the server, the sync button is greyed out.

My question is how do I set it up or what steps do I take so that the commit is pushed to the server?

[image]

Comment: You're confusing git and GitHub.  It looks like you don't actually have a GitHub repo.  You need to add a remote.

Comment: I have a repo on my online profile. Is it just a matter of setting it up to link to visual studio?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It looks like you do not have the upstream remote / branch configured for this branch. Visual Studio operates as if the "push.default" configuration is set to "upstream".

If you go to the branches page, this branch should be listed under the "Unpublished" branches section. From that page, you can choose to "publish" this branch by right clicking on the unpublished branch and selecting publish in the resulting context menu. This will push the branch to the origin remote (with a branch of the same name as your local branch) and set the upstream tracking information for this branch. From then on, you can push and fetch from the Unsynced Commits page.

Here is a screen capture of where you need to go to publish an unpublished branch:

[image: Publish an unpublished branch]

Comment: Okay, so I opened the branches page, shows unpublished branches --> Master, but there is no clear option to "publish" as you stated..Any idea as to why?

Comment: If you right click on the unpublished branch, it should be in resulting context menu.

Comment: Also I went to the un-synced commits page, but the options to "sync" , "pull/push"  are greyed out. Is there some setup I have to do before I can push?

Comment: The "sync", "pull/push" commands are all disabled until there is a configured upstream branch.

Comment: I right click on the unpublished brance, just gives me option to view branch

Comment: I added a screen image of where you need to go to publish an unpublished branch. Hopefully this will make it more clear. If this is not what you see, then we would have to see what else is going on.

Comment: I get the same screen but when I right click the only options it gives is, New Brance,Merge or View History. It does not allow to publish

Comment: I also found out today that the remote repo has to be named "origin" in repository settings, otherwise the Publish Branch option will be greyed out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the online GitHub repo as a remote in your local git repo.

On the command line, that's `git remote add origin <urL>`; I don't know if the VS git UI exposes this.

Comment: I get the `syntax of the command is incorrect`, is the url parameter the address of the repo on my git hub account?

Comment: No; it's the URL field on the lower right of the repo page

Comment: Ok I'm still getting the same error, is there a set of commands to execute before this line? At present I'm just opening git on the cmd and doing the above command.

Comment: Did you remove the arrows?

Comment: Tried without the arrows and it shows a new empty prompt. I'm guessing this means it was successful?

Answer (score 2):

We use Atlassian Stash but also found the Visual Studio UI a bit confusing at first.  The sequence that works for us, using **only the UI**, is as follows:

1. First you have to add your "username" and e-mail address in the Git global settings via Team Explorer > Home > Git > Git Settings
2. On the "Solution Explorer" tab, right click on the solution and "Add Solution to Source Control" and choose Git.
3. On the "Team Explorer" tab, click on the repo you just created and go to branches
4. Choose the master branch, right click on it and choose "Publish" - you will be asked for the remote URL whereupon after you enter it, you will get a username/password prompt (for the remote server i.e. GitHub, Stash, etc.)

   - All this is doing is `git push origin master`but Microsoft chose to make it confusing by giving it another name.
5. Wait for the "publish" to be completed (there will be a file transfer status shown in the UI)
6. Once it is completed, go to the commits tab and you will see that all the options for Push/Pull/Fetch etc are available

**Note:** If you create another branch locally, you will have to push, er "publish", that one as well before the remote knows about it.

**Final note:** Visual Studio will not create projects and repos for you on the remote.  You have to make sure the repo is setup on the remote before you can push a branch to it.

**Weird issue:** We found that if you try to push to a branch but fail (due to incorrect URL or a permissions issue) that we had to go back to the command prompt to "fix" the remote configuration for the repo/branch.  This is using the standard git command:

`git remote add origin https://myuser@stash.mycompany.com/scm/myproject/myrepo.git`

Comment: Update: Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise) automatically reads the configuration from your /git repo folder.  I didn't have to do any setup within the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

After you publish a branch as in @jamill's answer you may run into this.

In Team Explorer, I was able to publish a branch, but then I could not do anything.  Pull and Push were grayed out as shown:

[image]

So I did **Actions > Open Command Prompt**.  Then Type:

```
git push origin My_Branch_Name
```

After doing this I could see the branch and my commit in my remote.  (Github or whatever in your case).  Also when running the command, the output said,

```
remote: Create pull request for My_Branch_Name:
```

If you want to keep this branch and merge it into master, then you can create a pull request on your remote.  Otherwise as in my case I want to abandon the branch.  You don't have to do anything.

Comment: Kinda weird.  I think I just made it work only using the UI in visual studio.  Maybe it's a UI thing.  I right clicked the branch and did `Publish`.  Shrug.